Expanding a dataframe based on its column values
I have a dataframe called unmatched. In this dataframe, I have 4 columns called Numbers,    Year, Source_number, and    Target_number.
If for a given Numbers, there are values in both Source_number  and Target_number, then I want to expand the dataframe to include a second Year column so that it matches for both Source_number and Target_number.
For example, I want to change this:

to this:

Here is my code so far, and unfortunately it does not work:
expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Numbers', 'Year_source', 'Year_target', 'source_number', 'target_number'])

for unit_no in unmatched['Numbers'].unique():
    unit_rows = unmatched[unmatched['Numbers'] == unit_no]
    
    if unit_rows['source_number'].notna().any() and unit_rows['target_number'].notna().any():
        source_desc = unit_rows.loc[unit_rows['source_number'].notna(), 'Year'].values[0]
        target_desc = unit_rows.loc[unit_rows['target_number'].notna(), 'Year'].values[0]
        source_number = unit_rows.loc[unit_rows['source_number'].notna(), 'source_number'].values[0]
        target_number = unit_rows.loc[unit_rows['target_number'].notna(), 'target_number'].values[0]
        
        new_row = pd.DataFrame({
            'Numbers': [unit_no],
            'Year_source': [source_desc],
            'Year_target': [target_desc],
            'source_number': [source_number],
            'target_number': [target_number]
        })
        expanded_df = pd.concat([expanded_df, new_row], ignore_index=True)
        
        # Add the remaining rows for the current 'Numbers'
        remaining_rows = unit_rows[~(unit_rows['source_number'].notna() & unit_rows['target_number'].notna())]
        expanded_df = pd.concat([expanded_df, remaining_rows], ignore_index=True)
    else:
        expanded_df = pd.concat([expanded_df, unit_rows], ignore_index=True)

# The final expanded dataframe
print(expanded_df)

If anyone could provide any help I would greatly appreciate it, thank you!
